# In ElasticSearch how to check if a field exists that it equals some value, or that the field doesn't exist?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I want to find all documents in elasticsearch, where my "updated" field exists and is less that some value or where the field doesn't exist in the document at all. I can see that using a bool query, and must and must not can be utilized but how do I get the exact scenario I am trying to achieve with them?

Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming `updated` is a `date` type of field the query would look as below:

```
GET test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "exists": {
                  "field": "updated"
                }
              },
              {
                "range": {
                  "updated": {
                    "lte": "2019-06-10"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": [
              {
                "exists": {
                  "field": "updated"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Explanation of above:**

Let,

- Field `updated` should exists ===> `A`
- Field `updated` should be less than `X` ===> `B`
- Field `updated` should not exist at all ===> `C`

The required condition translates to `(A AND B) OR C`

Let `(A AND B)` be `D`

Now in terms of elastic it becomes:

```
should 
{
   D,
   C
}
```

#### OR

```
should
{
   must
   {
      A,
      B
   },
   C
}
```

In the above query only [range query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html) is sufficient and there is no requirement to check for the existence of updated field using [exists query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html) along with the range.

So the query can be rewritten as (B OR C):

```
GET test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "range": {
            "updated": {
              "lte": "2019-06-10"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": [
              {
                "exists": {
                  "field": "updated"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, you are beauty. As a beginner in ES, it helped me a lot. Thanks.