# Filter on field value or not exists

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to filter a field for a specific value OR that it does not exist.

I have the part for the specific value

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "app.serviceType": {
        "query": "MY_VALUE",
        "type": "phrase"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'd also like to add to this any case where the field `serviceType` doesn't exist at all.

Essentially I'd like the equivalent of this:

`serviceType == "MY_VALUE" || string.IsNullOrEmpty(serviceType)`

Comment: Do you seen this reponse : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56590057/in-elasticsearch-how-to-check-if-a-field-exists-that-it-equals-some-value-or-th/56591014

Comment: @YLR no, that result didn't come up in my search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This request must match with your use case :

```
 {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "exists": {
                  "field": "serviceType"
                }
              },
              {
                "match_phrase": {
                    "serviceType": "MY_VALUE"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": [
              {
                "exists": {
                  "field": "serviceType"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That didn't work but it did get me close. I had to change the first `must` at the beginning of the query to `should`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the previous answer (which didn't work but got me close) I was able to get it to work.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "exists": {
                  "field": "app.serviceType"
                }
              },
              {
                "match_phrase": {
                  "app.serviceType": "MY_VALUE"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": [
              {
                "exists": {
                  "field": "app.serviceType"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```